# Chains and Antichains: Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Suppose $(P,\preceq)$ is a poset, and let $L=\{a,b\}\subset P$  with $a\preceq b$. Let $S=P\times L$.

Let $A$ be any antichain in $S$.

Let $B$ be the largest possible subset of $P$ such that $B$ does not contain a chain of length of size exceeding $2$.

Show that card $A\leq$card$B$.

I am just stuck at this and don't know even where to start.

Comment: This makes little sense unless you define an order on $S$.

Comment: @egreg That’s what I was thinking, but in the source there is no order defined on S

Comment: @Jimmy: If that's what you're thinking, then you're actually thinking _something_ about the problem, and then "don't even know where to start" is not a fair summary of your thoughts about the problem ...

Comment: Does your source talk about a (natural) way to order a product of two posets? In this case, since $L$ has at most 2 elements, there is a *very* natural way to do it.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, the order on a product is the coordinatewise ordering -- that is, $(x, y) \leq (x', y') \iff x \leq x' \land y \leq y'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One natural way to put an order on $S$ is to say: $(p_1,l_1)\leq (p_2,l_2)$ iff $p_1\preceq p_2$ and $l_1\preceq l_2$. If this is the case, you can consider $A_a=\{x\in P\mid (x,a)\in A\}$ and $A_b=\{x\in P\mid (x,b)\in A\}$. Clearly, $A$ is a disjoint union of $A_a\times\{a\}$ and $A_b\times\{b\}$, so $|A|=|A_a|+|A_b|$.

Note that $A_a\cap A_b=\emptyset$, because if $x\in A_a\cap A_b$ then $(x,a)\prec (x,b)$ in $A$, and $A$ is not an antichain. Thus $|A_a|+|A_b|=|A_a\cup A_b|$.

Both $A_a$ and $A_b$ are antichains: if $x,y\in A_a$ is such that $x\prec y$, then $(x,a)\prec (y,a)$ in $A$, and $A$ is not an antichain. Similarly for $A_b$. So $A_a\cup A_b$ cannot contain a chain of length more than 2, because otherwise some two elements in such a chain would belong to $A_a$ or $A_b$. Since $B$ is some largest subset of $P$ with this property we have $|A_a\cup A_b|\leq |B|$.